# Insert image into SQL Server with express framework js

Tags: node.js, json, sql-server, express, byte

I would like to insert image in column of type `image` in SQL Server with node js.

The data comes from json with an array of bytes.

And in return display the image on pug

Comment: it is not who administers the database I have already found it so ...

Comment: @Larnu: or preferably `VARBINARY(MAX)` for binary files - like images

Comment: You're right, had a derp there, @marc_s .

Comment: @Larnu: well - if the image were base64 encoded before storing - your option would be perfect ;-)